# how to perform the flexbox in bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-vue

I am using the flex box in `vue.js` but the project cannot perform the functionality. the code is

```
<div class="d-flex">
          <div class="p-2"><p>Resturants</p></div>
          <div class="ml-auto p-2"><b-icon icon="three-dots-vertical"></b-icon></div>
        </div>
```

and the output is [the output image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m7tw.png)

can you elaborate how to solve this task.

Comment: What are you expecting it to look like?

Comment: I expect to show one in left side and other in right side..

Comment: can't advise without seeing your css. it looks like other css is overriding the bootstrap styles.

Comment: I have not add css for this. I use only bootstrap-vue

Comment: It can't be blue background, white text and corner-rounded without css styling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment, so i'll try to create an answer.
As other have suggested, it's strange that your box looks like this, without any css applied on.
What might be, is that the box is taking css from other components.
In every vue component, write the  tag as follows

```
<style scoped>
```

this will apply the css only to that certain component.
Regarding your question, you could do something like this

```
<div class="row row-flex">
  <div class="col-6">Content1</div>
  <div class="col-6">Content2</div>
</div>
```

And then add your css.
Hope it helped